# .NET 6 React - Fetch FileContentResult for download as PDF from Byte Array

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, react-native, .net-6.0

I am having some issues getting a file to download correctly to browser when a user clicks it. At the moment, the file is downloading, but the data seems corrupted because when I open the PDF, I get the error message "something went wrong". The file size is very small too, all of the bytes being passed from the controller do not seem to be making it to the file for download.

My controller, grabbing data from API as byte array and passing it back:

```
  [Route("GetForm/{formType}/{formId}")]
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetForm(string formType, long formId) {

        byte[] fileBytes = ApiClient.GetForm(formType, formId);

        return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
    }
```

And the React side of things:

```
downloadForm = (content) => {

        const getTaxFormDownloadlUrl = window.location.origin + '/GetForm';
        fetch(`${getPaymentTaxFormDownloadlUrl}/${statements.Formtype}/${statements.Formid}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            responseType: 'blob',
        }).then((res) => {

            var blob = new Blob([res], {
                type: 'application/pdf',
            });

            const element = document.createElement('a');
            element.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            element.setAttribute('download', content.Formtype + ".pdf");
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            element.click();
        });
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The response contains a URL, when I go to the URL to the controller call GET call, when it runs, it'll build the file and download it again. In this case, the file downloads correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having an onclick event, which was calling downloadForm(). I decided to dynamically create links to the GetForm controller call in React, therefore, when the link is clicked the controller is called, returning the file. The downloadForm logic was able to be deleted completely. Basically, I just added the file name to the GetForm `return File()` to make everything good.